# What is the result if I read after a uncommited update within the same transaction

Tags: database

I'm using Google App Engine with Java JPA.
The isolation level is Serializable inside transaction; Repeated Read outside transaction.

I search a lot of articles and everybody talks about behaviors between transactions, but no one mention about **read within the same transaction**.

Example :

```
/* data in User table with {ID=1,NAME='HANK'}  */

BEGIN;
UPDATE User SET name = 'MING' WHERE ID=1;
SELECT name FROM User WHERE ID = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Result : Still {ID=1, NAME='HANK'}

My Questions:

1. Does Isolation level setting affect queries within the same transaction?
2. What is the rule with the same transaction?

Comment: Yes i did. but I don't know what is the rule with the same transaction and I'm confused.

Comment: Different DBMS have different answers, I believe.  Specifically, the answers for Oracle are probably different from most other DBMS.  Did you have a specific DBMS in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Any queries done within the same transaction will be immediately visible to itself.  In your example if you read row with ID of 1, you will see that it is updated.  The difference is how other users are affected by your transaction.  Depending on your isolation level the other user may:

- Get blocked, the other user will wait until you commit / rollback
- Read the data as it was before the transaction (snapshot isolation)
- Read the data that is most up-to-date even without you committing (read uncommitted)

I'm just scratching the surface of isolation levels, there have been a lot of books written on the subject.